# Waiting for any process to finish in bash script

Tags: bash, process, background-process, jobs

I am trying to check how many active processes are running in a bash script. The idea is to keep x processes running and when one finished then the next process is started.

For testing purposes I set up this script:

```
find $HOME/Downloads -name "dummy" &
find $HOME/Downloads -name "dummy" &
find $HOME/Downloads -name "dummy" &

while true
do
    pids=()
    while read pid; do
        echo "PID: $pid"
        pids+=("$pid")
    done < <(jobs -p)
    
    jobs -p

    echo "Active processes: ${#pids[@]}"
    if [ ${#pids[@]} -lt 2 ]; then
        break
    fi

    echo "Process(es) still running... ${pids[@]}"
    sleep 1
done
```

But this does not work because `jobs -p` continues to return the job ids even when the processes have finished.

The following example shows the problem in detail:

```
#!/bin/bash

find $HOME/Downloads -name "dummy" &
find $HOME/Downloads -name "dummy" &
find $HOME/Downloads -name "dummy" &

while true
do
    jobs -p # continues to print all 3 jobs
    sleep 1
done
```

How can I get the active jobs in the `while` loop?

Regards,

Comment: You are probably asking the wrong question. You want to use `wait -n -p var` in a loop to wait for the next job to finish and keep track of which jobs have not yet finished yourself, rather then seeing which jobs have not yet reported their exit status.

Comment: See what `parallel(1)` is (its basic variant or GNU `parallel`). *Maybe* you're trying to reinvent it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. ``parellel`` seems indeed an option but I have already setup all my scripts. The hint from @icarus using ``wait -n`` was easy to integrate into the existing scripts and works great.

Comment: You might check my post here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654362/a-universal-while-read-something-to-parallel-conversion-replacement/654367#654367. This can run any mix of commands it is given. I think `parallel` will only run many instances of the same command.

Comment: @icarus: If you post your reply as an answer then I can set it as the accepted answer (because I am using your solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the script is that there is nothing in it which is going to call one of the wait system calls. Generally until something calls wait the kernel is going to keep an entry for the process as this is where the return code of the child process is stored. If a parent process ends before a child process the child process is reparented, usually to PID 1. Once the system is booted, PID 1 often is programmed to enter a loop just calling wait to collect these processes exit value.

Rewriting the test script to call the shell builtin function `wait` we get

```
pids=()
find $HOME/Downloads -name "dummy" &
pids+=( $! )
find $HOME/Downloads -name "dummy" &
pids+=( $! )
find $HOME/Downloads -name "dummy" &
pids+=( $! )

echo "Initial active processes: ${#pids[@]}"
for ((i=${#pids[@]}; i>1; i--)) ; do 
do
    wait -n # Wait for  one process to exit
    echo "A process exited with RC=$?"
    # Note that -n is a bash extension, not in POSIX
    # if we have bash 5.1 then we can use "wait -np EX" to find which
    # job has finished, the value is put in $EX. Then we can remove the
    # value from the pids array. 

    echo "Still outstanding $(jobs -p)"
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 3):

While `wait -n` (per comment @icarus) works in this particular situation, it should be noted that`$!` contains the PID of the last process that is started. So you could test on that as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

find $HOME/Downloads -name "dummy" &
p1=$!
find $HOME/Downloads -name "dummy" &
p2=$!
find $HOME/Downloads -name "dummy" &
p3=$!
while true
do
    if ps $p1 > /dev/null ; then
        echo -n "p1 runs "
    else 
        echo -n "p1 ended"
    fi
    if ps $p2 > /dev/null ; then
        echo -n "p2 runs "
    else 
        echo -n "p2 ended"
    fi
    if ps $p1 > /dev/null ; then
        echo -n "p3 runs "
    else 
        echo -n "p3 ended"
    fi
    echo ''
    sleep 1
done
```

But `parallel` is a better option.

Comment: The way I read the OP's question I took it to mean that they might want to launch different processes depending on which one finished. Yes the OP needs to use $! to populate the array (or other data structure) with the job details. I suspect your solution will not work for the same reason the OP had problems, nothing is calling one of the `wait` system calls so the processes are left in the process table. `parallel` **might** be a better solution.. Writing a Makefile (perhaps by a program) and using `make -j3`  or ksh93 with JOBMAX might also be better solutions, we don't have enough data.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to check how many active processes are running in a bash script. The idea is to keep x processes running and when one finished then the next process is started.

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel -j3 find $HOME/Downloads -name {} ::: "name1" "name2" "name3"
```

If you need to run different programs (and not just different arguments):

```
parallel -j3 ::: "find $HOME/Downloads -name name1" "find $HOME/Downloads -name name2"  "find $HOME/Downloads -name name3"
```

If the commands are more complex, use bash functions:

```
find1() {
  find $HOME/Downloads -name "name1"
}
find2() {
  find $HOME/Downloads -name "name2"
}
find3() {
  find $HOME/Downloads -name "name3"
}
export -f find1 find2 find3
parallel -j3 ::: find1 find2 find3
```

If you leave out `-j3` it will run one job per CPU core.